# (Urgent) Remove "Abstract" title and content from document

Tags: document-classes, abstract, layout, wlscirep

I need help trying to remove abstract and all the content that is included in my document. Can anyone help me please immediately? What I am posting is the wlscirep and the main.tex.

wlscirep

```
%
% An unofficial LaTeX class for Scientific Report articles.
%
% Copyright Overleaf (WriteLaTeX) 2016.
%
% Based on the SelfArx document class.
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
% \ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[18/03/2016, v1.1]
% \ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[03/11/2016, v1.2]
% \ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[27/02/2017, v1.3]
\ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[08/08/2020, v1.4]
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}   % Loads the Times-Roman Math Fonts
\RequirePackage{helvet}
\RequirePackage{courier}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}

\RequirePackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

% Settings for the author block
\RequirePackage{authblk}
\setlength{\affilsep}{1.5em}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\fontsize{12}{12}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}}

\RequirePackage[left=2cm,%
                right=2cm,%
                top=2.25cm,%
                bottom=2.25cm,%
                headheight=12pt,%
                letterpaper]{geometry}%
                
\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf},%
                labelsep=period,%
                justification=raggedright]{caption}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

% Set up of the bibliography style

% \RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[superscript,biblabel,nomove]{cite}
%% Nov 3, 2016: Support DOI
\bibliographystyle{naturemag-doi}
              
%
% headers and footers
%
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}  % custom headers/footers
\RequirePackage{lastpage}  % Number of pages in the document
\pagestyle{fancy}          % Enables the custom headers/footers
% Headers
\lhead{}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{}%
% Footers
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{\small\sffamily\bfseries\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% % No footer rule

%
% section/subsection/paragraph set-up
%
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1}
  []  
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries\itshape}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []    
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1} 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pc}{2.5ex \@plus3pt \@minus2pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{2ex \@plus2.5pt \@minus1.5pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{1.5ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{10pt}

%
% tableofcontents set-up
%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{section}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{4pt}\small\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents{subsection}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{2pt}\small\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[\tocsep]
  {\footnotesize\sffamily}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  [\ \textbullet\ ]  
  
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
%\setlist{nolistsep} % Uncomment to remove spacing between items in lists (enumerate, itemize)

% Remove brackets from numbering in List of References
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\bfseries\color{color1}#1.}

%
% article meta data
%
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\def\@keywords{#1}}

\def\xabstract{abstract}
\long\def\abstract#1\end#2{\def\two{#2}\ifx\two\xabstract 
\long\gdef\theabstract{\ignorespaces#1}
\def\go{\end{abstract}}\else
\typeout{^^J^^J PLEASE DO NOT USE ANY \string\begin\space \string\end^^J
COMMANDS WITHIN ABSTRACT^^J^^J}#1\end{#2}
\gdef\theabstract{\vskip12pt BADLY FORMED ABSTRACT: PLEASE DO
NOT USE {\tt\string\begin...\string\end} COMMANDS WITHIN
THE ABSTRACT\vskip12pt}\let\go\relax\fi
\go}

%
% custom title page 
%
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@title\par}%
\vskip10pt
{\raggedright\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@author\par}
\vskip18pt%
{%
\noindent
{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\color{color1}\large\sffamily\textbf{ABSTRACT}}}
}%
\vskip10pt
{%
\noindent
\colorbox{color2}{%
\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
\sffamily\small\textbf\\\theabstract
}%
}%
% \vskip18pt%
% \noindent
% \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
% {\color{color1}\keywordname\hspace*{1em}} \@keywords%
%}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}%
}%
%-----------------------------------------------
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm} % Distance between the two columns of text 
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt} % Width of the border around the abstract

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,0} % Color of section headings
\definecolor{color2}{gray}{1} % Color of the box behind the abstract
\newcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords:} % Defines the keywords heading name

\newlength{\tocsep} 
\setlength\tocsep{1.5pc} % Sets the indentation of the sections in the table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Show only three levels in the table of contents section: sections, subsections and subsubsections

\usepackage{lipsum} % Required to insert dummy text
%-----------------------------------------------
\let\oldbibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace*{-\tocsep}\refname}%
\oldbibliography{#1}%
\setlength\itemsep{0pt}%
}
%% Automatically abbreviate journal names
\RequirePackage{jabbrv}
```

And here is the main.tex

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{A}

\author[1]{}
\affil[1]{Affiliation, department, city, postcode, country}


\affil[*]{corresponding.author@email.example}
\date{}

%\keywords{Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3}

\begin{abstract}
Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations.
\end{abstract}
\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle
% * <john.hammersley@gmail.com> 2015-02-09T12:07:31.197Z:
%
%  Click the title above to edit the author information and abstract
%
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Please note: Abbreviations should be introduced at the first mention in the main text – no abbreviations lists. Suggested structure of main text (not enforced) is provided below.


\section*{Section 1: Introduction}



\section*{Section 2: Results}



\subsection*{Context}


\subsection{Throrem 1}




\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{itemize}

\begin{equation}
 a^n + b^n = c^n   
\end{equation}

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx}{dt} &=& ax + by +cxy ~~~  \text{when} x>0 \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &=& cx + dy+ e\sqrt{xy} ~~~\text{when}~y<\infty
\end{eqnarray}

\subsubsection*{Third-level section}

Topical subheadings are allowed.

\section*{Discussion}

The Discussion should be succinct and must not contain subheadings.

\section*{Methods}

Topical subheadings are allowed. Authors must ensure that their Methods section includes adequate experimental and characterization data necessary for others in the field to reproduce their work.

\bibliography{sample}

\noindent LaTeX formats citations and references automatically using the bibliography records in your .bib file, which you can edit via the project menu. Use the cite command for an inline citation, e.g.  \cite{Hao:gidmaps:2014}.

For data citations of datasets uploaded to e.g. \emph{figshare}, please use the \verb|howpublished| option in the bib entry to specify the platform and the link, as in the \verb|Hao:gidmaps:2014| example in the sample bibliography file.

\section*{Acknowledgements (not compulsory)}

Acknowledgements should be brief, and should not include thanks to anonymous referees and editors, or effusive comments. Grant or contribution numbers may be acknowledged.

\section*{Author contributions statement}

Must include all authors, identified by initials, for example:
A.A. conceived the experiment(s),  A.A. and B.A. conducted the experiment(s), C.A. and D.A. analysed the results.  All authors reviewed the manuscript. 

\section*{Additional information}

To include, in this order: \textbf{Accession codes} (where applicable); \textbf{Competing interests} (mandatory statement). 

The corresponding author is responsible for submitting a \href{http://www.nature.com/srep/policies/index.html#competing}{competing interests statement} on behalf of all authors of the paper. This statement must be included in the submitted article file.

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{stream}
\caption{Legend (350 words max). Example legend text.}
\label{fig:stream}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Condition & n & p \\
\hline
A & 5 & 0.1 \\
\hline
B & 10 & 0.01 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:example}Legend (350 words max). Example legend text.}
\end{table}

Figures and tables can be referenced in LaTeX using the ref command, e.g. Figure \ref{fig:stream} and Table \ref{tab:example}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have cleaned up a series of comments here. The summary of them is that TeX-sx works best for problems that have some generality, and at present this question feels very much like a one-off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `comment` package and surround the `abstract` with `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}`.

```
% noabstractprob.tex  SE 564380

\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{comment}  % PW added
\title{Report on Factoring Forms}

\author[1]{Sam Osakue}
\affil[1]{Affiliation, department, city, postcode, country}


\affil[*]{corresponding.author@email.example}
\date{september 22, 2020}

%\keywords{Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3}

\begin{comment} % PW added
\begin{abstract}
Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations. Example Abstract. Abstract must not include subheadings or citations.
\end{abstract}
\end{comment} % PW added

\begin{document}

% an so and so forth until \end{document}
```